# How to prevent infinite loops when setting an image source via onError in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Scenario: Let's say that I have a `<img/>` whose `src` is generated dynamically based on some value like so:

```js
    <img className="icon" src={"./" + this.props.name + ".png"} alt="icon" />
```

I want to avoid a broken image so I change the src on error like so:

```
<img
    className="icon"
    src={"./" + this.props.name + ".png"}
    alt="icon"
    onError={
        (event) => {
            console.log(this.props.name + ".png missing from public folder");
            event.currentTarget.src = "./unknown.png";
            event.currentTarget.onerror = null;
        }
    }
/>
```

This works *as long as* the image alternative I give actually exists. If it doesn't, it will end up in an infinite `onError` loop despite me adding the `event.currentTarget.onerror = null;`

How should I go about preventing this? Is it possible?

P.S.: I found alternatives, for example [react-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image) but I was wondering if there's a native solution. I could also directly edit the DOM with jQuery, but I would rather not mix react with jQuery.

Comment: Simply use a local image that you know will be here.

Comment: @Sylvain "just make sure the code is correct" isn't really an answer :) I'm asking if it's possible to fix this directly.

Comment: I wonder if an approach like this would make more sense than mutating `event.currentTarget.src`: https://codepen.io/halfninja/pen/VaYmby. (Personally, I'd change their code a bit and use a functional component, etc. But I like the idea of handling the error cases like that.)

Comment: @ReedDunkle I think that approach might be cleaner. Do you know any reason why mutating the src is a bad idea?

Comment: @Mike No, I don't. I try to avoid mutations in React. But this is the first time that I've seen the `onError` prop, and I did see another [example](https://medium.com/@webcore1/react-fallback-for-broken-images-strategy-a8dfa9c1be1e) where the person mutates the `src`.

Comment: Is `onerror` an HTML prop or is it just a React thing? The problem might be that it's stripped off by the time you start mutating it inside of the `event.currentTarget`?

Comment: `onerror` is html. However, I noticed when console logging `event.currentTarget` that only the `src` existed, no `onerror`. Thought that was interesting. Console logging `event.currentTarget.onerror` returns null, even when removing all other `onError` logic

Comment: onerror is html, yes. And it apparently doesn't appear in the displayed html, it only exists within the JavaScript context. I think you're right in saying that it gets stripped away during rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be as clean as you're looking for, but a solution I've used before is to use `onError` to set a flag in state instead of changing the `src`:

```js
const [imgError, setImgError] = React.useState(false);

if (!imgError) {
  return (  
    <img
      src={"./" + this.props.name + ".png"}
      onError={() => setImgError(true)}
    />
  )
} else {
  return <img src="./unknown.png" /> // with no onError
}
```

I separated it into its own component so that I just use `<Image/>` like a normal `img` tag and it handles its own errors.

Comment: That's an interesting approach! Though, right now I am waiting to see if anyone knows of a way to prevent this loop directly.

Comment: I've accepted your answer since no one else answered.